# django custom field in admin inline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Here's admin.py:

```
class AnsweredQuestionInline(ReadonlyTabularInline):
    model = AnsweredQuestion
    fields = ('question', 'selected_choice', 'one_answer')

    def one_answer(self, obj):
        return obj.get_answer()


class CompletedTestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnsweredQuestionInline]
```

When I go to completed test admin interface I get this error:

```
Exception Type: FieldError at /admin/tests/completedtest/5/
Exception Value: Unknown field(s) (one_answer) specified for AnsweredQuestion
```

Is it possible to add custom fields for django's inline admin ? If so what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 15):

All you need is `readonly_fields = ('one_answer', )` in your `AnsweredQuestionInline` class

Comment: This suggestion works and should be accepted as the answer!